# Sold mutual funds, Fidelity told my bank I was selling too quickly

Tags: mutual-funds

I had a fund with Fidelity (targeted, retirement) for many years.  Lately, I sold all of it and bought a Vanguard fund.  Shortly after my bank sent me a letter saying that Fidelity contacted them and said, as I understand it, that I was selling too frequently.  Why would this happen?

Comment: Is that _literally_ what the letter said? What is the _exact_ wording of the letter? I suspect your interpretation is incorrect. Was the original fund in an IRA? Is the Vanguard fund in an IRA also?

Comment: Did you inadvertently trigger a good faith violation? https://www.fidelity.com/trading/faqs-trading-restrictions

Comment: Read [this](https://www.optionshouse.com/margins-buying-power/good-faith-freeride-violations/) to understand some of the complicated trading rules you may have violated. It should not be a big deal, just explain that the violation was accidental and won't happen again. There are typically no penalties for a single violation anyway.

Comment: Why would Fidelity send a letter to your bank and not to you directly?